Continuity of a family of linear mapping
QUESTION: Let $X$ be a Banach space and $(A_t)_{t\in \mathbb{R}} \subset \mathcal{L}(X)$ a family of continuous functions on $X$. If we still know that the mapping $t \mapsto A_tx \quad \forall x \in X$ is continuous, can we assume that the mapping: $$A:X \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow X$$ $$(x,t) \mapsto A_tx$$
is continuous?
Due to the reasons mentioned, I know that it is continuous in the individual components, therefore in $t$ as well as in $x$, but I am unsure whether it really also applies to the cross product, as it is generally not the case. Can someone perhaps give me tips on whether the statement is true at all and how it could be shown.
